# nslookup returns communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out; no servers could be reached

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, configuration, dns

I am following a tutorial on YouTube about Nginx and as I follow him, I received an error from the dns container. At first I can run docker-compose build but docker-compose up fails because of systemd-resolved is using port 53. I was able to fix using instructions from this link. [listen tcp 0.0.0.0:53: bind: address already in use #65](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-bind/issues/65)

Now, when I run docker-compose up and it didn't fail but when I test it using command nslookup, I received an error like no servers could be reached. (FYI: I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on my machine).

> ;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
> ;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
> ;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
> ;; no servers could be reached

**dns/zone/main.com**

```
$ttl 86400
@       IN      SOA ns.main.com.    hostmaster.main.com.(
                    202 ; Serial
                    600 ; Refresh
                    3600 ; Retry
                    12378237) ; Expire

@       IN      NS  ns.main.com.
ns      IN      A   127.0.0.1
```

**dns/Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk add bind openrc
RUN rc-update -u named
```

**dns/named.conf**

```
options {
    directory "var/bind";
    allow-transfer { "none"; };
    allow-query { any; };
    listen-on { any; };
};

zone "main.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zone/main.com";
};
```

**nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ns.main.com;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/main;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

**nginx/Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./html /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/html/:/usr/share/nginx/html/
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
  dns:
    build:
      context: ./dns/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 53:53
      - 53:53/udp
    volumes:
      - ./dns/named.conf:/etc/bind/named.conf
      - ./dns/zone/:/etc/bind/zone/
    command: named -c /etc/bind/named.conf -g -u named
```

Hope you can enlighten me. Looking forward to improve. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try some things

**Try 1**

Remove one of the line (by setting twice port 53, you confirm that port 53 is use)

```
    ports:
      - 53:53
      - 53:53/udp // delete line
```

---

**Try 2**

```
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/html/:/usr/share/nginx/html/
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
  dns:
    build:
      context: ./dns/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - <ANOTHER_PORT>:53 // change <ANOTHER_PORT> with an available port
    volumes:
      - ./dns/named.conf:/etc/bind/named.conf
      - ./dns/zone/:/etc/bind/zone/
    command: named -c /etc/bind/named.conf -g -u named
```

Comment: The first try works man. Thanks a lot!